# C++ iterating std::accumulate() over a map of unique_ptr: no known conversion

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap

This is probably a case of Friday afternoon blindness... why is the accumulation over the map not working. It hands me a compile error

```
main.cpp:35:80: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::pair, std::unique_ptr >’ to ‘const std::pair, std::unique_ptr >&’
```

What is wrong with this cast?

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    long bar() const {return 1;}
};


int main()
{

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v;

    auto baz = [](long x, const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p){return x + p->bar();};

    std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0L, baz);



    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;

    auto bam = [](long x, const std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& p) {
        return x + p.second->bar();
    };

    std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0L, bam);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value_type` of [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is `std::pair<const Key, T>`; note that the key is qualified as `const`. So for `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` the `value_type` is `std::pair<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`, but not `std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`. Because of `std::unique_ptr`, a temporary `std::pair<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` can't be copy-constructed from `std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` (and bound to parameter `p` with type of reference to `const`).

You can change the lambda's parameter's type to match the `value_type` exactly, then the argument could be bound directly.

```
auto bam = [](long x, const std::pair<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& p) {
//                                    ^^^^^
    return x + p.second->bar();
};
```

You can also use [member types of `std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#Member_types) like `value_type` or `const_reference`.

```
auto bam = [](long x, const std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>::value_type& p) {
    return x + p.second->bar();
};

auto bam = [](long x, std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>::const_reference p) {
    return x + p.second->bar();
};
```

Comment: not Friday afternoon blindness... I did not know that. Thanks a lot. Something learned this week, still. I guess 'auto' got me through life so far without having to know this;)

Comment: @chrise You can also use `value_type` directly, if you think remember such details is boring. (But I still suggest you remembering them. :) )

Comment: why `const map_t::value_type &` and not `map_t::const_reference`?

Comment: @Caleth Nice alternative; added.